# How to stop entry in AppPool .config file from reappearing

Tags: iis, iis-7

I traced an issue down on one of our servers to an incorrect section in the .config file for an AppPool. If I manually remove the section from the c:\inetpub\temp\AppPools\thisAppPool.config which relates to one specific asp file (let's say site/epub/webservice.asp) then the web services work fine. However, if I then change a setting in IIS Manager, it overwrites this and re-adds the incorrect section.

I know how I can specify settings around authentication etc at the Virtual Directory level, but not at the file level (other than by editing the config file, which then gets lost).

Any ideas how I can stop this problem returning (other than by never changing things in the IIS Manager!)?

OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20100420044047/http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-File-Level-Authentication-in-IIS-7-75.aspx) to enable File Level Authentication in IIS 7/7.5 using IIS Manager. Also check the entry that can be seen in the apphost.config file. I hope you are entering the setting correctly.

There are few bugs in IIS 7.5 which are supposed to be fixed with the SP1 release.

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for. Somehow this one asp file had been set to run as an invalid user!